# tf.exe Unable to detrmine the workspace

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, workspace, cmd

I am trying to call TF get command via Team Build script. I am getting the following error

> Unable to determine the workspace.

Folks over the internet tell that this error is because Team Build cannot find the workspace because it is being called from a directory which is not part of the workspace.

The solution presented is to specify the working directory. I do so. The mappings are ok in Build Definition path as well as in the workspace. But now i get the following error:

> Could not find cmd.exe in the current
>   directory . The directory name is
>   invalid.

Kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: **cmd.exe.** I did a type when writing down the error here in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I added one more binding in my build Definition Workspace Section and referenced files to get/checkin/checkout with the help of variable $(MSBuildSourceDirectory). Meanwhile I ensured that $(SourceDir) is used to specify mapping in the workspace section of my Build Definiton dialog.

[image: Workspace binding in build definition dialog]
<sub>(source: [geekswithblogs.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121022547/http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/MikeParks/Team%20Build%20260%20Character%20Path%20Limit%20Workaround%202.jpg))</sub>

At the same time i encountered 260-character path limit, so i modified the output directory in build path as described **[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200920141234/http://geekswithblogs.net/MikeParks/archive/2009/06/20/team-build-260-character-path-limit-workaround.aspx)**

[image: 260-character path limit]
<sub>(source: [geekswithblogs.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121023257/http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/MikeParks/Team%20Build%20260%20Character%20Path%20Limit%20Workaround%201%281%29.jpg))</sub>